# Locking code in python without access to parent thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm new to Python, so I'm sorry if what I'm asking is dumb!

I have a piece of code which can be used by mutliple threads in Python. There is a section of it which needs to be locked so only one thread can process it at a time.

Typically I would do this with a semaphore. The problem I have in this particular scenario is that I don't have access to the code which initiates the threads where I could define the semaphore so that all threads have access to it.

I thought if I made the semaphore a class variable, it would only create one instance of the variable which would be shared by all instances of the class as follows:

```
class SubscriptionDetails:

   sema = Semaphore(1)



   def __init__(self):
       ...
       print 'sema: '+str(id(SubscriptionDetails.sema))



   def add_to_global(self):
       SubscriptionDetails.sema.acquire()
       ...
       SubscriptionDetails.sema.release()
```

But when I look in the logs, I can see the address printed out for sema as part of the '**init**' method in the class is different each time. I can also see overlapping threads running the same part of the code that was supposedly locked.

Is there a way around this with only access to the code that is used by the child threads?

Comment: for me, the code is correct, and I get for each SubscriptionDetails-object the same sema-id. Can you show us a minimal example, where the error occurs?

Comment: Ok, I'm glad what I have is sound! The area I'm not sure about is how the thread / process is getting initiated that runs this code. I'm a Java coder and my understanding in Java is that as long as it is part of the same VM, a class instance variable will be the same for all class instances. Is this true in Python? I **think** the code is getting initiated by some C or C++ code as this is part of an python script addon for XBMC.